# 401 Unauthorized while subscribing to push notifications with Exchange service and OAuth

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, exchangewebservices

I am trying to access EWS managed API (subscribe to push notifications) with oauth as below:

```
var authenticationTask = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com", new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret));
string targetSmtp = "user123@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com";
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
exchangeService.Url = someURL;
exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
exchangeService.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "user123@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com");
exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", targetSmtp);
exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authenticationTask.AccessToken);
PushSubscription subscription = exchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
                                            new[] { someFolder },
                                            new Uri(postBackUrl),
                                            15,
                                            null,
                                            EventType.NewMail,
                                            EventType.Created,
                                            EventType.Deleted,
                                            EventType.Modified,
                                            EventType.Moved,
                                            EventType.Copied);
```

I am able to get the token for my app but while subscribing the user (user123@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com) for push notifications I get `"The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."` error

Update: tried following the exact same step mentioned here: [Azure AD app-only access tokens for exchange impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491143/azure-ad-app-only-access-tokens-for-exchange-impersonation/42503475) but still getting 401.

[Ashish](https://www.sharevidya.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those struggling with the same issue, we need to get the access token for the registered app by using a certificate (instead of doing it with client secret key). For more details on how to do it please see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/